# Can we use role ="tablist" for div . As this is not properly working with Jaws. It looses the focus

Tags: focus, roles, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

Can we use role ="tablist" for div . As this is not properly working with Jaws. It looses the focus .

```
<div role="tablist">
    <h3>
        <div tabindex="-1" role="tab" aria-setsize="3" aria-posinset="2">
            Page 2
        </div>
    </h3>
</div>                 
<div role="tabpanel" aria-selected="false">                     
    <p>Test Slide div and looses focus.</p>                 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

- Add `aria-multiselectable="true"` to the `tablist` div
- Add `aria-labelledby="tab1"` to the `tabpanel` div
- Add `id="tab1"` to the `tabindex` div
- Add `id="panel1" aria-hidden="false"` to the `tabpanel` div
- Add `aria-controls="panel1" aria-expanded="true"` to the `tabindex` div

**References**

- [WAI-ARIA 1.1 Authoring Practices](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices/#accordion)
- [Example - Tab Panel: Accordian1](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/accordion/accordion.html)